# 'npm-run-all' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, npm-start, npm-init

#Command : npm run dist #Bootstrap Command #Error: 'npm-run-all' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Installed Node.js along with chocolatey. Everything added to path. Running this code on VS CODE terminal in bootstrap extracted file directory.

Answer (score 1):

First try "npm -v" and "node -v" in cmd. If they are present only then continue further. Else install them.

change the cd to bootstrap folder (Extracted zip file from bootstrap website) and Run the following command in your VS CODE terminal.

"npm i"

This helped me hope it helps you too :)